# refactoring multiple if-else conditionals in a method

Tags: java, refactoring, conditional-statements

I am in the process of refactoring my existing code. It actually works fine, but it is a bit cluttered with multiple if-else conditionals checking the value of one variable and change the value of a second variable to an updated value taken from a fixed enumeration structure.

```
else if (var1 == 'valueX')
{
    if (var2 == MyEnum.A)
        var2 = MyEnum.B;
    else if (var2 == MyEnum.B)
        var2 = MyEnum.C;
    else if (var2 == MyEnum.C)
        var2 = MyEnum.D;
    else if (var2 == MyEnum.D)
        var2 = MyEnum.A;
}

else if (....)
{
..similar block of conditionals
}
```

I am a bit confused as to what is the best way to refactor and clean-up this code. Would you suggest the use of a switch perhaps? Or something more elegant?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least with J2SE 1.5 forward, you can give enums extra attributes. This means you might be able to replace that entire string of if-else with something that looks like

```
var2 = var1.getNextInSequence();
```

Now, in this case, it looks like you would want the attribute to be a reference to another enum, which adds some wrinkles, for example you can't forward reference enums when you initialize them, but there might be a workable solution for you this way.

When the attributes aren't other instances of the same enum, this kind of thing will work:

```
public enum Animal {
    FOX(4),
    CHICKEN(2),
    WORM(0);

    private int countLegs;

    Animal(int n) {
        countLegs = n;
    }

    public int getLegCount() {
        return countLegs;
    }
    // .. more getters setters etc
}
```

But when the enum is self-referential, you have to be careful about the order of declaration of your instances. I.e., this will have some issues:

```
public enum Animal {
    FOX(4, CHICKEN),    // 'CHICKEN' doesn't exist yet
    WORM(0, null),
    CHICKEN(2, WORM);    // this actually will compile

    private int countLegs;
    private Animal eatsWhat;

    Animal(int n, Animal dinner) {
        countLegs = n;
        eatsWhat = dinner;
    }

    public int getLegCount() {
        return countLegs;
    }
    // .. getters, setters, etc
}
```

So if you had need of a circular set of references among the enums, you'd have to work something else out, but if not, you *could* use this technique, though you may have to order your enum instances just so to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for the analysis! So basically I need to create a method to get the next in sequence from my enum.

Answer (score 6):

The classic answer to refactoring conditionals is [Replace Conditional With Polymorphism](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html).  In this case, if each of MyEnum knew what its successor was, you could simply say (in the 'valuex' case: var2 = var2.successor.  For var1 - if it could be an object that implemented an interface that knew how to handle whatever you're doing inside the loop, and each implementing class knew what it, specifically, should do... Well, you'd be done.

**Update:**

And here's a dandy little successor function in a test case:

```
public class EnumTest extends TestCase {
    private enum X {
        A, B, C;
        public X successor() {
            return values()[(ordinal() + 1) % values().length];
        }
    };

    public void testSuccessor() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(X.B, X.A.successor());
        assertEquals(X.C, X.B.successor());
        assertEquals(X.A, X.C.successor());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the update! This looks really interesting. Will give it a try.

Comment: There's no polymorphism in your code. Sure, in this case, it's clearly better than defining `successor` three times, but you should make it clear.

Comment: I understand your point, @maaartinus: this isn't classic polymorphism as implemented through inheritance, but I disagree.  When two different entities behave differently, just because of what they are, that's polymorphism for the purpose being discussed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple map:

```
enum MyEnum { A, B, C };

Map<MyEnum, MyEnum> VALUE_X = new HashMap<MyEnum, MyEnum>() {{
    put(MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B);
    put(MyEnum.B, MyEnum.C);
    ...
}};

// define another kind of ordering
Map<MyEnum, MyEnum> VALUE_Y = new HashMap<MyEnum, MyEnum>() {{
    put(MyEnum.A, MyEnum.D);
    put(MyEnum.B, MyEnum.A);
    ...
}};
```

This way, the logic of the next `var2` value isn't hard-coded in the enum itself, and can be dependant of context (i.e. value of `var1`):

```
if ("valueX".equals(var1)) {  // use equals() instead of == for Strings
    var2 = VALUE_X.get(var2);
}
else if ("valueY".equals(var1)) {
    var2 = VALUE_Y.get(var2);
}
```