# Java Refactoring - Replace Conditional with Polymorphism

Tags: java, refactoring, polymorphism

I made some research about refactoring my college code. I used JDeodorant plugin for Eclipse and it throws me away, that something like that:

```
if (object instanceof Class1) {
    do_something1();
} else if (object instanceof Class2) {
    do_something2();
} else if (object instanceof Class3) {
    do_something3();
}
```

should be replaced by Polymorphism. 
Everything will be fine, except that all methods do_something() refer to operations not related with object. So for me polymorphism will not work.

Is there any other way to avoid using instanceof , which seems to be unprofessional.

Thank You very much.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396166/refactoring-and-removing-case-statements-when-circling-over-an-enum-structure?rq=1

Comment: What are Class1, Class2 and Class3. Do they all extend a common class or implement a common interface?

Comment: Yes, they expands the same base class

Comment: Then put the method in the sub classes.

Comment: operations are not related with subclasses., so it is not the best solutions.

Comment: Then perhaps you should have a look on your general architecture...