# Help with enums in Java

Tags: java, enums

Is it possible to have an enum change its value (from inside itself)? Maybe it's easier to understand what I mean with code:

```
enum Rate {
    VeryBad(1),
    Bad(2),
    Average(3),
    Good(4),
    Excellent(5);

    private int rate;

    private Rate(int rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

        public void increateRating() {
            //is it possible to make the enum variable increase?
            //this is, if right now this enum has as value Average, after calling this
            //method to have it change to Good?
       }
}
```

This is want I wanna achieve:

```
Rate rate = Rate.Average;
System.out.println(rate); //prints Average;
rate.increaseRating();
System.out.println(rate); //prints Good
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  You could simply call

```
rate = Rate.Good;
```

for this specific case.  But what I think you are really looking for is a successor function.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215207/refactoring-multiple-if-else-conditionals-in-a-method/1215225#1215225) you are:

```
public class EnumTest extends TestCase {
    private enum X {
        A, B, C;
        public X successor() {
                return values()[(ordinal() + 1) % values().length];
        }
    };

    public void testSuccessor() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(X.B, X.A.successor());
        assertEquals(X.C, X.B.successor());
        assertEquals(X.A, X.C.successor());
    }
}
```

Comment: + 1. This is probably the best way to go. Nice succinct code too.

Comment: But... the `Rate` it self won't change is it?

Comment: @Oscar I think the idea is that devoured would do something like `rate = rate.successor();`

Comment: In my example, just call `x = x.successor();`  Yours would probably look more like `rate = rate.nextRating();` (depending, of course, on how you name the function).  If you want to change the value of the enum itself - not a variable which holds the enum - no, that's not possible.

Comment: The only comment, in `successor()` method `values()` should probably be cached.  It is called twice and the operation has a non-trivial cost.

Comment: I'll +1 if you move your comment to the answer, for that's the real answer ***No, that's not possible, but you can etc. etc***   This alternative is really enlightening, but I can't upvote you because the systems says: *Vote to old to be changes, unless this answer is edited*  :-D

Comment: @Oscar Reyes I'm going to leave it as a comment.  I *think* the OP's question is satisfactorily addressed by the answer itself, although it is ambiguous, and certainly possible that s/he really wanted this in the form of a void function.

Comment: Well the problem with your approach is that I can't do something like Rate rate = Rate.Good; like an enum would.

Comment: @devoured elysium: yes, you can do exactly that.  It's still 100% an enum.  It's just that this lets you take an existing rate and - without checking its value - assign its successor.  `Rate rate = Rate.Average; rate = rate.successor();`  Simple as that.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. I had already implemented that. The problem is having to make rate = rate.sucessor(). I'd like to do instead just rate.sucessor(), but I guess it just isn't possible at all.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

```
class Rate {
    private static enum RateValue {
        VeryBad(1),
        Bad(2),
        Average(3),
        Good(4),
        Excellent(5);

        private int rate;

        public RateValue(int rate) {
            this.rate = rate;
        }

        public RateValue nextRating() {
            switch (this) { /* ... */ }
        }
    }

    private RateValue value;

    public void increaseRating() {
        value = value.nextRating();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The example in the question tries to change the value of "rate" by calling a method on it. This is impossible, enum values are objects, so you cannot change them for the same reasons you cannot assign a new value to "this". The closest thing you can do is add a method that returns another enum value, as proposed by Carl Manaster.

Comment: +1 : The real original question (as clarified by "This is want I wanna achieve") only has this answer: no, you can't.

Comment: Yes, I think I came to the same conclusion myself.

Answer (score -1):

It should be possible but I have to admit that I've never tried it. In the end enums are just objects with a little twist so you should be able to do that unless you define the rate field as final.